# Codiad on OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I have Codiad installed on a free gear at OpenShift.

I forgot my username / password to Codiad.

I have Putty running and the root of my machine looks like the image below:
[image]

I also have access to the app itself, here is a screen shot below:
[image]

Does anyone know where the username and password is stored for the Codiad login?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

The password is stored in the Codiad/data/users.php file.

There you can edit the password field using a text editor.